# How to add a <font-family> for dynamic HTML text?

Tags: android

I am getting HTML text as a response from backend which has bold and italic styles in between, when i add app:fontFamily="@font/font_regular" it does not highlight bold and italic data, complete text will be regular
so how to handle dynamic spannable data with fontfamily in android

this is a xml file for font_regular which is present inside font folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:font="@font/sf_ui_display_regular_cyrillic"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="700"
        app:font="@font/sf_ui_display_regular_cyrillic"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="700"  />
</font-family>
```

any help to get rid of this scenario  without using typeface.
thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to use spannables. Search on how to convert html to spannable.